# What does this 'make up to' mean?

Tags: vocabulary

> [q] Managers who go on to earn engineering degrees can **make** up to
>   $100,000 a year.
>   -- [corpus.byu.edu/coca](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/)

What does ‘make’ mean?
I guess it might be either [a] or [b] below from [Merriam-Webster’s Learner’s](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/make).

> [a] 14 a [linking verb] — used to indicate a total
>  [b] 17 [+ obj] : to
>    earn or gain (money, a profit, etc.)

But I’m not sure, for [q] has prepositional complement which I don't find in dictionaries. Which mean do I have to take? Can the prepositional phrase be used with the one you select?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that managers who go on to earn engineering degrees can earn an annual salary that may be as high as $100,000 per year.

Comment: up to ($100) = as high as ($100)

Answer (score 4):

It's Definition 17. Definiately 17. The word *make* in that context refers to salary; under Definition 17, *make* is a synonym of *earn*.

> *I made $18,000 when I first started working here.*

Most native speakers would assume that the $18,000 figure in that sentence referred to an annual salary, unless additional context specified otherwise.

As for Definition 14, that's more of an arithmetic use of the word:

> *Twelve donuts make a dozen*.